# Git workflow with features branch & team work

Tags: git, workflow, branch

I have been looking recently into git workflows, and which one would be the best for our team.

**What would be the best** (or one of the best) **git workflow that we could work with?** This workflow should respect some / most / all of the following points:

- 2 teams will use git (about 8 people each), both working on the same application. Each team may or may not have its private repository.
- The application has several versions. Beginning of the developpement of version (n+1) may start before the release of version (n). Dev on version (n+1) should not be included in version (n)
- The client may decide at the very last minute not to include Feature x in the next release, which was developped the month before.
- The project history should be easy to understand.

My workflow idea : a sligthly different workflow than the one that can be found here : http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

- One central repository for the two teams, available by SSH.
- Branch master is stable.
- No branch develop is created. Instead, each version of the application has its own branch, and the teams develop on them. Branch of version (n+1) is created from branch of version (n). Therefore, new devs can occur on branch (n+1) while there are bug fixes on branch (n).
- A branch is created for every new features & bug fixes, like in the models.
- Only one central repository for both team, because it doesn't seem easy to work with two main repositories for each team. **What would be a workflow with two repositories for each team ? Would it be worth it ?**
- Most (if not all) merge should not be fast forward because if fast forward occurs, there seem to be no ways to prevent Feature x from being included.
- Upon release, merge version (n) into master, and tag

**Also, wouldn't there be too many branches due to this strategy?** There can easily be about 30~ bug fixes after a release. If branches are made for every bug fix, there will be a lot of branches in no time. Any solution to avoid that?

Would a patch workflow be a good idea? What could it be? I would think that every bug fixes & features could have their own patch, giving the client the ability to choose which one he wants.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Git workflows like branching. You actually cannot prevent people from having private repos and branches (and it is a really stupid idea to try to control them like this: you'll loose the strongest point of distributed VCS). What you can control (only!) is the repositories you have direct access to: you can stop others from pushing their changes into it, or even close the access completely. In tightly controlled environments the direct pushing is usually not allowed: the changes are pulled by a dedicated team member from the others. Tested and afterwards pushed for team-wide use.

For the simple workflow you request, the strategy described in Pro Git book looks fitting: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows

See `git cherry-pick` for *very last minute, long done* features. `gitk` for history browsing (there is actually a lot of graphical tools for this). Public development and release(s) branches are just that, public branches, possibly with their own maintainers.

You might want to take a look at workflows facilitated by big Git hosting sites like **GitHub**. There are similar opensource implementations (like Gerrit by Android project) for these.

Comment: Actually, I meant that everyone has their local repository, and one central remote repository for both teams or two remote repositories for each team, or more than two for reasons I can't think of right now. Are you saying that only one person Mr. X should be able to push to a remote repository, and he pulls everything from the two other teams? Team members are then pulling from the remote repository or from Mr. X?

Comment: Only one person (the integrator), yes. "Remote repository" is not the word I would have used. It is "public repository". Where everyone pulls from. And yes, it is his task to collect the changes. Well, in reality it is more like: everyone's bugging him about pulling. Google for "pull request grumpy Linux kernel maintainer" :)

Comment: I am a bit worried though, wouldn't it add too many tasks for the integrator? If we follow a strategy of branching, with 15 people always creating new branches, I think it might give him a lot of work, even more if there are conflicts. We are planning to use an ssh repository, and working with Eclipse (EGit). We did not consider Github because we already have servers. Would it add functionality that we will not have with an ssh repository ?

Comment: How do you think Linux Kernel development works? They certainly have more the 15 people, all working at the same time on the very same code base. And I didn't say: use Github. I said: look at the workflows it facilitates. Yes, Github-like software would add functionality by streamlining these workflows.